# Функция Include в Entity Framework не загружает связанные сущности

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nunit

Покрываю проект NUnit-тестами. Возникла проблема с функцией Include.

```
var Testable = context.Testables
    .Include(f => f.TestableFilial)
    .Include(r => r.TestableReservLevel)
    .FirstOrDefault();

int idTestable = Testable.TestableId,
    idFilial = Testable.TestableFilial.FilialId, // вот здесь 
    idRL = Testable.TestableReservLevel.ReservLevelId; // и здесь не может обратиться к объектам, потому что они равны null
```

Модели:

```
public class Filials
{
    [Key]
    public int FilialId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Филиал")]
    public string FilialName { get; set; }
}

public class ReservLevels
{
    [Key]
    public int ReservLevelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Уровень резерва")]
    public string ReservLevelName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Описание уровня резерва")]
    public string ReservLevelDescription { get; set; }
}

public class Testables
{
    [Key]
    public int TestableId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Код")]
    public string TestableCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Дата создания")]
    public DateTime DateCreate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Дата последнего редактирования")]
    public DateTime DateEdit { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Филиал")]
    public Filials TestableFilial { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Уровень резерва")]
    public ReservLevels TestableReservLevel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Архивирован")]
    public bool isArchived { get; set; }
}
```

Самое странное, что везде эта функция работает, а именно в этом методе отказывается работать.

Comment: В приведённом коде ошибок нет, в compile time всё в норме. Можно всё-таки глупый вопрос: а есть уверенность, что TestableFilial = null а не таблица пуста и Testable = null?

Comment: Проверял через отладку. `Testable` там все поля заполнены, только Filial и ReservLevel null
Залез в SQL MS там все поля на месте.

Comment: Вы в тестах используете "боевую" БД? Или может там отдельная специально для тестов? И она пустая, не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я пока только тренируюсь в написании тестов. И это, как сказать, тренировочно-боевая база. На ней я тестирую новые функции, ну и теперь думал NUnut тесты на ней запускать. Короче, это не продакшн база.

Comment: Я почему уточняю: это очень распространённая ошибка - используются две (или более) БД и иногда путают строки подключения. В итоге работают не с той БД (пустой). Вот и советую проверить: к той ли БД подключаются тесты?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я ответ написал и забыл отправить. В этом-то и проблема, что тесты создали свою базу, но не добавили первоначальные данные, которые должны добавляться при создании базы, в итоге, я совсем не понимаю, как работают эти тесты. По идее, контроллер не должен пропускать добавление одинаковых кодов и не должен добавлять объекты с пустыми полями, но он всё равно их добавил. Я совсем запутался, кто куда и что добавляет. оэтому сейчас почищу обе базы и буду проверять кто и куда ломится.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему я нашёл. Заключалась вот она в чём: у меня есть строка подключения

```
<add name="AnketaConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(Local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Anketa_Main;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Должно подключаться к каталогу `Anketa_Main`, но почему-то создался новый каталог `AnketaConnection` и все запросы тесты записывают туда

[image: База]

И тесты почему-то подрубаются ко второй базе, у которой почему-то не заполнены таблицы, которые должны заполняться при добавлении.
[image: База]